# How do I pass every element of a list to a function as unnamed arguments?

Tags: r, do.call

Let's say I have some models stored in a list:

```
mods <- list()
mods[[1]] <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
mods[[2]] <- lm(mpg ~ disp + factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
mods[[3]] <- lm(mpg ~ disp * factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
```

And I want to compare them using `stats::AIC`. I'm looking for the output I would get from `AIC(mods[[1]], mods[[2]], mods[[3]])`, but I'd like it to generalize to an arbitrarily long list. I thought that

```
do.call(AIC, mods)
```

would work, but it returns something that's very verbose and unhelpful. (If the list is named, an error results unless one of the names is `object`, corresponding the the first argument of `AIC`, but then you just get the verbose output again.)

After the failure of `do.call`, I started thinking about an `eval(parse())` solution, but I figured I should ask here first.

Comment: can't you simply remove the rownames? (as in `test = do.call(AIC, mods); rownames(test) = NULL`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
summary(do.call(AIC, mods))
       df         AIC       
 Min.   :3   Min.   :153.4  
 1st Qu.:4   1st Qu.:159.6  
 Median :5   Median :165.8  
 Mean   :5   Mean   :163.1  
 3rd Qu.:6   3rd Qu.:168.0  
 Max.   :7   Max.   :170.2
```

But this likely isn't what you want.  Baptiste has the answer:

```
my.aic <- function(x) {
  x <- do.call(AIC, x)
  rownames(x) <- NULL
  return(x)
}
my.aic(mods)
##   df      AIC
## 1  3 170.2094
## 2  5 165.7680
## 3  7 153.4352
```

This is rather close to:

```
AIC(mods[[1]], mods[[2]], mods[[3]])
##           df      AIC
## mods[[1]]  3 170.2094
## mods[[2]]  5 165.7680
## mods[[3]]  7 153.4352
```

Comment: After using this for a bit, I'll say that it can disappointingly slow. The rownames that are put in by default can be gigantic, and they are then slow even just to remove. Although this answer seems like the "right" way to do it, I've switched back to the hack-ish `eval(parse())` solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `eval(parse())`. Luckily Matthew gave a better answer before I even had this typed up.

```
AIC_l <- function(L, FUN = "AIC") {
    args <- paste0("mods[[", seq_along(L), "]]", collapse = ", ")
    my_call <- paste0(FUN, "(", args, ")")
    eval(parse(text = my_call))
}
AIC_l(L = 1:3, FUN = "AIC")
```