# Create and Call Linear Models from List

Tags: r, list, lm

So I'm trying to compare different linear models in order to determine if one is better than another.  However I have several models, so I want to create an list of models and then call on them.  Is that possible?

```
 Models <- list(lm(y~a),lm(y~b),lm(y~c)
 Models2 <- list(lm(y~a+b),lm(y~a+c),lm(y~b+c))

 anova(Models2[1],Models[1])
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067519/using-r-to-do-a-regression-with-multiple-dependent-and-multiple-independent-vari/18069211#18069211) may be of help.

Comment: Does using `anova(Models2[[1]],Models[[1]])` work?

Comment: Note that the `anova` is most useful for nested models.

Answer (score 6):

If you have two lists of models, and you want to compare each pair of models, then you want `Map`:

```
models1 <- list(lm(y ~ a), lm(y ~ b), lm(y ~ c)
models2 <- list(lm(y ~ a + b), lm(y ~ a + c), lm(y ~ b + c))

Map(anova, models1, models2)
```

This is basically equivalent to the following for loop:

```
out <- vector("list", length(models1))
for (i in seq_along(out) {
  out[[i]] <- anova(models1[[i]], models2[[i]])
}
```

Map is an example of a functional, and you can find out more about them at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functionals

Answer (score 4):

You can use `do.call` to convert a list of any length into a call suitable for a function taking `...`.  The only trick here is that `anova` expects the first model to be named--that's what the `Curry` handles by creating a new function which already has its first argument specified.

Put everything except the first model (call it `lm1`) into one list called `Models`.

Then:

```
library(functional)
do.call( Curry(anova, object=lm1), Models )
```

Example:

```
> Models <- list( lm(runif(10)~rnorm(10)),lm(runif(10)~rnorm(10)),lm(runif(10)~rnorm(10)) )
> lm1 <- lm(runif(10)~rnorm(10))
> do.call( Curry(anova, object=lm1), Models )
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: runif(10) ~ rnorm(10)
Model 2: runif(10) ~ rnorm(10)
Model 3: runif(10) ~ rnorm(10)
Model 4: runif(10) ~ rnorm(10)
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq F Pr(>F)
1      8 0.46614                      
2      8 0.59522  0  -0.12908         
3      8 1.00869  0  -0.41346         
4      8 0.81686  0   0.19182
```

Comment: I am suprised too. Especially, because it doesn't work like that with `AIC`.

Comment: Follow-up question to get to the bottom of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108419/behavior-of-do-call-in-the-presence-of-arguments-without-defaults

Comment: @Roland see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16630776/903061) for a similar question with `AIC`.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- rnorm(100,0,1)
y <- rnorm(100,5,2)
z <- rnorm(100,8,1)    
models <- list(y.x = lm(y~x), y.z = lm(y~z))
anova(models[[1]],models[[2]])
```

This worked for me.