# Behavior of do.call() in the presence of arguments without defaults

Tags: r, arguments, do.call

This question is a follow-up to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108234/636656) which raised a puzzle.

Reproducible example from the previous answer:

```
Models <- list( lm(runif(10)~rnorm(10)),lm(runif(10)~rnorm(10)),lm(runif(10)~rnorm(10)) )
lm1 <- lm(runif(10)~rnorm(10))
library(functional)
# This works
do.call( Curry(anova, object=lm1), Models )
# But so does this
do.call( anova, Models )
```

The question is why does `do.call(anova, Models)` work fine, as @Roland points out?

The signature for anova is `anova(object, ...)`

`anova` calls `UseMethod`, which should* call `anova.lm` which should call `anova.lmlist`, whose first line is `objects <- list(object, ...)`, but `object` doesn't exist in that formulation.

The only thing I can surmise is that `do.call` might not just fill in ellipses but fills in all arguments without defaults and leaves any extra for the ellipsis to catch?  If so, where is that documented, as it's definitely new to me!

* Which is itself a clue--how does `UseMethod` know to call `anova.lm` if the first argument is unspecified?  There's no `anova.list` method or `anova.default` or similar...

Comment: isn't it the same situation as `do.call(plot, list(1:2, 1:2, col="red"))`? It seems to obey the standard behaviour re positional matching, named arguments and `...`.

Comment: I'm confused, what's puzzling about `do.call(anova, Models)` being the same as `anova(Models[[1]], Models[[2]], Models[[3]])`?

Comment: Because `do.call` is always talked about as a solution to `...`, I guess it's never mentioned that it will also fill in according to the positional matching rules.  But this was pretty surprising to me.

Comment: I really don't understand what positional matching rules you're talking about - can you please explain in a couple of sentences?

Comment: @eddi the positional matching rule is what baptiste referred to: empty arguments (those without defaults or which don't have named arguments specified) are filled in in order.

Comment: @SimonO101 seems like you're missing the point of the "*", rolling back, again...

Comment: `do.call` just does a basic lexical substitution from `do.call(f, list(...))` to `f(...)` - and you can always pass both named and unnamed arguments along to ...

Comment: @hadley Can you explain more?  "Basic lexical substitution...to `f(...)`" is similar to what I've read in other places, and is what led me to believe that it substitutes for `...` rather than following the usual positional, naming, unnamed rules.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman tried to describe it in the answer below - I think you're missing how ... works, not how `do.call` works

Comment: @hadley I agree that's where the confusion came from.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a regular function call `...` captures arguments by position, partial match and full match:

```
f <- function(...) g(...)
g <- function(x, y, zabc) c(x = x, y = y, zabc = zabc)

f(1, 2, 3)
# x    y zabc 
# 1    2    3     
f(z = 3, y = 2, 1)
# x    y zabc 
# 1    2    3
```

`do.call` behaves in exactly the same way except instead of supplying the arguments directly to the function, they're stored in a list and `do.call` takes care of passing them into the function:

```
do.call(f, list(1, 2, 3))
# x    y zabc 
# 1    2    3     
do.call(f, list(z = 3, y = 2, 1))
# x    y zabc 
# 1    2    3
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is worth stressing that **the names of the list elements do matter**. Hadley mentioned it, but it can be an annoyance. Consider the next example:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + 0.2

Models <- list()
Models$xy <- lm(z~x)
Models$yz <- lm(z~y)

# This will fail, because do.call will not assign anything to the argument "object" of anova
do.call(anova, Models)
# This won't
do.call(anova, unname(Models))
```

Answer (score 1):

`do.call` passes the first element of the list to the first argument:

```
fun <- function(x,...) {
  print(paste0("x=",x))

  list(x, ...)
}

do.call(fun, list(1,2))
# [1] "x=1"
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
```

Comment: what else could it possibly do?! isn't `do.call(f, list(1,2))` by definition supposed to be equivalent to `f(1,2)`? I'm really not getting the OP.

Comment: Well, we thought that would be the case for `f <- function(...)`, but not for `f <- function(x ,...)`. I expected the latter to give an error with `do.call`.

Comment: @eddi I could only substitute in for the `...` and return an error otherwise.  It's obviously more useful the way it actually works, but the most common usage is to fill in for the `...`.

Comment: :) not sure why you'd think that, but ok

Comment: We were wrong, but thinking that `do.call` would only fill in the ellipses doesn't seem far-fetched to me, though the examples section of the documentation shows otherwise.

Comment: This answer is wrong! If the elements of the list is named, the statement is false.

Comment: @AntoineLizée The list elements in the question are not named ... You cannot expect an answer to answer something that wasn't asked.

Comment: I'm not sure to totally agree with that. The spirit of SO is to answer something that is true in general, or make it clear if it is specific to the situation.